# Reading /dev/input/ of PS/2 keyboard

Tags: keyboard, input

I'm currently working on a project where I want to control my PC with an AVR, via emulating a PS/2 keyboard. For this reason I currently have all the required hardware and some software libs, such as https://github.com/ndusart/ps2-keyboard for the AVR and http://python-evdev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html for the PC part.
I also read about the PS/2 protocol from http://www.pcbheaven.com/wikipages/The_PS2_protocol/, http://www.computer-engineering.org/ps2protocol/ and http://retired.beyondlogic.org/keyboard/keybrd.htm

Then I've ran the command `sudo cat /dev/input/by-path/platform-i8042-serio-0-event-kbd > ./kbrd.hex` and connected a keyboard, then pressed and released the backspace.
I would except something like `AA 66 F0 66`, and maybe some `FA`'s (ACK) in between, but what I've got is ***very*** different:

[image]

So my question:
Could this be caused by my misunderstanding of the working behavior of /dev/input/, or the problem is in the other parts of my setup?
 I expect to get the raw input from the buffer from /dev/input/, and this isn't that I think the raw should be.

**EDIT**
Another hexdump AFTER plugging in the keyboard:
[image]

Comment: You can also use `evtest`, which will pretty print the `input_event` structure, to help you understand what is going on. Note that kernel input events are **not** the raw PS/2 protocol. If your question is how to access the raw PS/2 protocol, this needs some additional steps.

Comment: Is there a way to access the raw PS/2 port for doing low level byte reads and writes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you describe the process, you: started capturing output, plugged in the keyboard, pressed a key, then stopped capturing. If that is the case, I would recommend plugging in the keyboard, start capture, press key, stop capture?

**EDIT:** Adding additional information

I haven't gotten anything in my own quick research to fully line up with your dumps so far, but:

Per [kernel.org documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/input/input.txt) and [source code](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/input.h#L26), output from /dev/input interfaces is in the format:

```
struct input_event {
    struct timeval time;
    unsigned short type;
    unsigned short code;
    unsigned int value;
};
```

Which equates to:

- timeval: 16 bytes (8 bytes for seconds, 8 bytes for microseconds)
- type: 2 bytes

  - `01` for `EV_KEY` (keypress). See [input-event-codes.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/input-event-codes.h#L35)
- code: 2 bytes

  - `0E` for `KEY_BACKSPACE`. See [input-event-codes.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/input-event-codes.h#L65)
- value: 4 bytes `01` for keypress, `00` for release, `02` for autorepeat

Comment: Edited Question with another dump